# How do I get rid of onion weed in my garden beds?

Tags: weed-control

This weed grows from a bulb and if I try to pull it out apparently some bulbs or part of bulb stays behind because a few months later I have hundreds of them. I have heard it said I have to remove the clump of soil with the bulb but then I would have holes all through my garden. Is there a better way?

Comment: Where do you live? Could you describe the leaves? There are many plants who create bulbs. Do it smell like garlic? You may check also the flower you have. They may also produce bulbs. You question is too generic to be answered

Comment: Does this weed have white flowers, and is it about 6-8 inches in height when it flowers? Where are you in the world?

Comment: I’m in Queensland Australia, warm temperate climate, 800 m above sea level. Yes, it has little white flowers and is about 6-8 inches high. There are lots of baby ones now, perhaps because we had some rain a few weeks ago. Really, we are in drought. I tried pulling some up today and it has a strong onion smell.